# Merge two dataframes with same column names into one with a vector of the two values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, one of texts the other of ratings:

```
structure(list(Jessica = "tame.", Ashley = "The only"), .Names = c("Jessica", 
"Ashley"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

structure(list(Jessica = 3L, Ashley = 1L), .Names = c("Jessica", 
"Ashley"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")
```

)

I am hoping to create a data frame in which each cell is a vector of the two values so that I could easily convert into a json file with both text and ratings under the same key.

Here is how it should look like:

```
structure(list(list = list(c("tame.", "3", "The only", "1"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .Names = "list")
```

Comment: Can you please explicitly add your expected output for the sample data you provide?

Comment: Sorry for that - I updated my question.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. There is no entry `"seems tame"` in any of the initial `tibble`s. Is that meant to be `"tame."`? Why do you have two identical `list` entries in your expected output? Why do they get duplicated? Perhaps it helps if you were to provide a slightly larger (more than one single row) and more representative example and matching expected output. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks - maybe you were looking on a draft of my change. See Joe's response below. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

ds1 <- structure(list(Jessica = "tame.", Ashley = "The only"), .Names = c("Jessica", 
"Ashley"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

ds2 <- structure(list(Jessica = 3L, Ashley = 1L), .Names = c("Jessica", 
"Ashley"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")
)

ds2 <- ds2 %>% mutate_all(as.character)

ds3 <- bind_rows(ds1, ds2)

(ds4 <- 
    ds3 %>% 
    gather(Jessica:Ashley, key = name, value = value) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(list = list(value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(list)
)

ds4$list[1]
```

Comment: Perfect Joe! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to long first (`gather`) and merge, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 %>% 
 gather(var, val) %>% 
 left_join(d2 %>% gather(var, val), by = 'var')
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   var     val.x    val.y
>   <chr>   <chr>    <int>
> 1 Jessica tame.        3
> 2 Ashley  The only     1
> ```

Comment: Thanks but the goal is to have a list of the two values in each cell.